# 2.80: Pie menus and Quick Favorite menu - conflict?

Tags: add-on, shortcut, quick-favorites

When I have the 'UI Pie Menu Official' activated I cannot open the Quick Favorites Menu when pressing q. All I get is another pie menu with possible view port option (top, front, left etc.)

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Pie Menus are enabled by default in blender 2.8, so you no longer need to enable the addon.  So now the q key will work as quick favorites.

But how do you get the view pie menu that the addon previously provided with key q?  Well, that's now the backtick key (`).  You can see all the pie menu key mappings under the user_preferences->keymap and filtering on pie:

[image]